# Hide keyboard in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How can I hide my keyboard when I click on my UIImageView?

I am trying to use this soution but it does not work with UIImageView:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender 
{

logLang.hidden=YES;
pasComp.hidden=YES; 
[login resignFirstResponder];
[password resignFirstResponder];


}
```

Comment: First of all i would like to know when your keyboard appear? key-board always appear for when you are entering any text on textField.

Comment: yes and i want click in my UIMageView and hid keybord

Comment: i can do this with my view but if use UIMageView it not work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image view **`user interaction`** enabled in xib? if you are adding your imageView pro grammatically then

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        if ([touch view] == yourImageView) {
             logLang.hidden=YES;
             pasComp.hidden=YES; 
             [login resignFirstResponder];
             [password resignFirstResponder];
        }
 }
```

**use the UIResponder methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc to detect the touch on the image view**

Comment: but i use XIB and i not declar new UImageView haw i can find "yourImageView"?

Comment: What is the name of your image view in the xib file, i just gave you an example(**so i assume that your imageView name is yourImageView**)